# Roasting 3 Stuffed Pork Loins

Tags: pork

I am roasting 3 stuffed pork tenderloins together.  If the timing for one is 30 minutes, how long should I roast 3? (A digital thermometer will be used to measure internal temp.)

Comment: Basically the same as "If one egg needs to boil for five minutes, how long does it take to boil a dozen eggs?" Upvoted!

Answer (score 4):

30 minutes. Provided you have some space between them so the air can circulate, it doesn't matter how many you roast at once.